# Reference for the classification of (singular) degree 4 surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{C}}$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

I was told singular quartic algebraic surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{C}}$ have been completely classified and their singularities have been described.
Can anyone provide me with a resource where this classification is described, in particular the possible combination of singularities on such surfaces?

A search provided http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/preprint/file/RIMS1370.pdf, but i am wondering if there's something in one of the published books? I did not find anything in Reid - chapters on surfaces, and Beauville's book on surfaces treats only smooth surfaces.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of classification are you looking for? Just in terms of singularities? 

Comment: @Ottem, yes maybe i should have said this more clearly in the first place. My question should actually be: "What are the possible combinations of singularities on quartics in $\mathbb{P}^4$? Furthermore, for each such possible combination, can we say anything else about the surface?"

Comment: In fact, maybe i should say something about the application i have in mind. I have a quartic surface $V$ and a plane $W$  in $\mathbb{P}^3$, and i know $V$ is not singular along a curve in $V \cap W$. I would like to determine the possible singularities that $V$ can have along the curve $V \cap W$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the classical book by C. M. Jessop [*Quartic surfaces with singular points*](http://archive.org/details/cu31924062545383) (1916).

The paper by C. Segre *Etude des différentes surfaces du 4-eme ordre à conique double ou cuspidale*,  Math. Ann. **24** (1884), no. 3, 313–444 is also useful.

At any rate, I do not know if there exists a really *complete* classification.